# Where would I go to learn write code that had to be very, very secure but DOES expose external services (running on a standard Windows or Linux OS)

Tags: windows, linux, security, service

Where would I go to learn write code that had to be very, very secure and that DOES expose external services (running on a standard Windows or Linux OS). Knowing what services can and cannot be safely exposed would be part of the issue. Note that I am not looking for a favorite choice between Linux and Windows, as the choice is not likely to be mine to make in any given case. However the level of security needs to be military grade.

I almost feel embarressed giving this as a for instance, but how would I know whether or not I could use, say, WCF, in such a setting.

Comment: Just a side note "military grade" doesn't seem to mean much anymore.

Comment: I prefer the term "lawyer-grade" - they're more bound to fry you than the government in most cases.

Comment: 'very secure' is not a meaningful term. If there is an answer to your question, it depends on what asset you are securing (information? control?) what threat you are worried about, and what economic cost is associated with a breach. Usually, the biggest threat to security is social engineering and/or corrupted wetware (person bribed to steal the data or open a port), not devious malware, unless you are the Iranian nuclear engineering department or have otherwise annoyed some Israelis.

Comment: By Military grade I just mean the sort of security you would want if you were the military of just about any country i.e. the kind of security you would want to have against a very powerful, very determined adversary like a rival country.

Comment: Secure transit of information and secure control.

Sure there are human factor vulnerabilities, but I can't control those. I just want to make sure I know how to make sure that human factors are the only viable risk.

Comment: Military organizations use a wide variety of mechanisms, ranging down to gmail, depending on the **details** of what they are trying to accomplish. There is no such single thing as 'military security'.

Comment: Climb a high mountain, and if you find a programming guru there grovel at his or her feet and beg to be accepted as a acolyte?

Answer (score 2):

High security is a difficult concept as it generally involves way more than just the code you wrote.

Basically every layer of the [OSI model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) has to be taken into consideration.  Things like, preventing capture of the data stream (or it being rerouted) between the end points ([quantum cryptography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_cryptography)).

At the higher levels, you have things like various things like

1. Physical security of the devices (all endpoints if possible).
2. Hardening the OS (e.g: closing ports, turning off unused services, using kerberos, VPN tunnels, and leveraging white lists of machines allowed to connect, etc);
3. Encrypting the data at rest (file encryption), in transmission (SSL), and in memory (column/table encryption).
4. Ensuring and enforcing proper authentication and authorization at every level (in app, in sql, etc).
5. Log EVERYTHING.  At a minimal it should answer "who/what/when/where/how"
6. Along with the logging, Actively Monitor it.  aka: intrusion detection.

Then we can move on to other things like looking at other attack vectors like sql injection, xss, internal / disgruntled employees, etc.

And once you've done all of that be prepared when a hacker gets away with everything they want simply by social engineering.

In short, the best tact to take in order to secure any computer related application is to listen to the ethos of Fox Mulder, and Trust No One. Another favorite of mine that applies is: It's only paranoia if they aren't after you.

Comment: Yes, exactly. The code I didn't write is exactly what concerns me. Not that I can't make mistakes, but the its the invisible mistakes (in the style of Hacking: The Art of Exploitation) that concern me most. However since money isn't just disappearing out of my bank account like a sieve (well, unless I spend it) then at least banks have accomplished reasonable security, and presumably the military, IRS, etc.... With all the hidden layers, how do they do it? How would I learn to do it?

Comment: @John: Your first step is going to be to research the keywords I had above. e.g. file encryption, sql server encryption, etc.  Each of these are going to lead you down paths that will open up other areas of research.  Another area to look at are the current off the shelf toolkits for cracking apps, like metasploit.  Everything I learned about how to properly implement security started with first learning how to crack sites, apps, etc.  Once you understand the myriad of ways to take something down you'll start to understand how to protect them.

Comment: Be careful with "log everything". It's easy to create a denial-of-service attack filling up a server's HD with log entries. Or it can make legitimate issues hard to find because they're buried inside many GB of chaff.

Comment: @Gabe:  I brought up the logs for a few reasons.  If the logs are properly structured you will be able to rebuild the actions of an individual or group.  These are absolutely required in order to track the attacker down and prosecute if necessary.  If the data / app is that important then buying racks of drives just for logging should be a minor expense.

Comment: stackoverflow.com is great for your general programmer question, but are there other better communities for learning about this?

Comment: @John: The problem is twofold.  First  this is an extremely broad topic and no one site/location is going to have all of the information you want.  Second, attack vectors and defenses change *daily*.  Start with reading some sites like seclists.org and www.hackernews.com.  They look like they were done by 5 year olds, but I guarantee spending a few days reading those sites and you'll understand the scope of the problem you are faced with.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [formal methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_methods) to (sort-of) prove the critical parts of your software. A tool like [Frama-C](http://frama-c.com/) (free, LGPL license, targetting embedded systems) could be relevant (at least if your software is critical, embedded, written in C).

But military grade don't mean much. Your client will (and *should*) define exactly the standards to respect. For instance, critical [civilian] aircraft software needs to follow something like [DO-178C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DO-178C) (or its predecessor, DO-178B). Different industries have different standards similar to that. (both railways and medical industries have their own standards, which might be different in North America than in Europe).

If your system (& client) is less demanding (i.e. no billion dollars or hundreds lives threatened by bugs) you could consider customizing your compiler or using some other tool. For example, [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) is customizable thru plugins or thru [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) extensions.

Don't forget that software reliability has a big price (that means a big cost for you, hence for your client).

Answer (score 0):

Well, the question of where can be answered simply. Not in school. I suggest to create a learning path for yourself. Pick a technology that you like and learn it inside out. A basic book to get you started should suffice, however the rest of the stuff you learn as you go, or via the documentation of that technology.

For instance - learning under .NET (Microsoft) involves a basic A-Press text-book (i suggest Pro C# and The .NET 4.0 Platform). Thereafter searching through the .NET Framework Reference on MSDN will give you the rest.

If you are looking for WCF reference, I suggest the (MCTS Exam 70-503, Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 Windows Communication Foundation) and MSDN.

Just keep in mind that not a single technology will achieve what you are looking for. For example: WCF co-mingles with WF (Windows Workflow Foundation), as well as SQL Data Services and Entity Framework. Being exposed to multiple technologies will definitely broaden your vision.

===============================================================================

WCF is a beast in this regard. Here are the advantages over some other means of communication:

Messages (data) passed between end points can be secured via message-level security (encryption). The transport channel chosen can also be secured at protocol level via transport layer security (encryption).

End points themselves can authorize and impersonate clients (client level security). You can implement end-to-end service tracing, health monitoring & performance counters, message logging, as well as forward and backward compatibility with newer/older clients (via graceful degradation of the message format, provided in WCF). If you chose to do so, you can even implement routing as fail-safe for your communications channel. WCF also supports transactions (ACID), concurrency, as well as a per-instance throttling, giving you the most flexibility in writing secure/robust military grade code.

In retrospect the security and flexibility of WCF are astonishing. A similiar technology (if not the same) is the WS-Security spec. It is part of the WS-* specifications for web services and deals with Xml signature and Xml encryption to provide secure communications channel between two end points.

The disadvantages of WS-* however is that it is a one-way means of communication. WCF can facilitate 2 way communication. A client can send a request to a server, but also a server can send requests to the client. WS-* dictates that a client can only send and receive responses to the server, but not vice versa.

I am not a WCF developer so i thought the highlights might provoke you into doing your own research. "There are hundreds of ways to skin an animal, neither of them is wrong..."